javadoc generated document annotation content Chinese garbled code
javadoc generated document annotation content Chinese garbled code.
The red frame is garbled, and the rest is normal
Editor IDEA JDK1.8.
javadoc -d doc -encoding UTF-8 -charset UTF-8 -docencoding UTF-8
Invalid use of the above command!!
